# Unable to Navigate to the Given File Path in Selenium Python on Ubuntu Machine

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, file-upload, navigation

I have been facing this problem for a couple of weeks. I am unable to upload a file using Selenium in Python. The given path is correct, and it gets stuck at /home, but my file is located in /home/e/Downloads/BulkFile.csv. I am using Ubuntu so how can I overcome from this issue.
Here is image where it got stuck :

I am looking for your best answer.
Thank you

It should be directed into  given path and select that file to upload.